# ethanol/water %vol/vol and freezing temperature

Tags: phase, melting-point

**Main Question:** Where can I find a table (or realistic formula) for isopropanol/water %vol/vol **mixes** and corresponding freezing temperature with public access?

**Background:**
Trying to get the freezing point of my car windshield wash fluid.

**What I have tried so far:**
Anti-freeze is may be ethanol or isopropanol. I got tables for ethanol/water %vol/vol and temperature, but could not find them for isopropanol. I learned that for ethanol the calculated (using simple formula) freezing temperature does not match the real one if using high concentrations, so this is likely true also for isopropanol, and why I am asking for this table.

**Additional bonus question:** is there a (household-practical) way to determine what was filled (and possibly even mixed during garage service): ethanol/isopropanal-based anti-freeze...?

(PS: wasn't sure about which forum, chemistry, physics... - please guide me if this question belongs somewhere else)

Comment: Googling ‘ isopropyl alcohol water phase diagram’ yields what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but actually I am having a hard time to find proper results: they refer to the vapor pressure or other alcohols...  Can find multiple dataon ethanol, even just inthe Wikipedia datapages, but not for isopropanol/isopropyl alcohol (tried several variants) That's why I was asking.

Comment: Ethanol/water: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethanol_(data_page); isopropanol/water e.g. on https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/ispropanol-water-d_988.html  The bonus question: no, as far as I know my tools in the kitchen, not with household items.

Comment: Thanks - may sound simple to you but exactly what I was looking for and could not find. Can you post as answer so that I can acept it?